# Schengen visa application to France and Italy

Tags: schengen, france, italy, business-travel, los-angeles

I am an Indian PhD student in UCLA traveling to France (11 days, for a conference) and Italy (15 days, for a research collaboration) on April 22nd.

The conference in France is the main purpose of the trip. But I am confused as to which embassy where I should apply to. Also, the Italian embassy in LA does not have any open slots for the entire month of April so I would like to apply to France :-)

Does anyone know whether the French embassy in LA will reject my application? Their website (http://www.consulfrance-losangeles.org/spip.php?article789) is very clear that I should apply to the country where I will stay the longest. In particular, they mention nothing about the "apply to country that is the main destination" clause at http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/how-to-apply-schengen-visa.

(update: I am hoping that the 11 days vs. 15 days might swing it in my favor, any ideas / recent experiences?)

Comment: The clause says it's **recommended** to apply where you will spend more time, so there are exceptions like your case. However some embassies continue to insist you apply where you will spend more time. Email each embassy as to their specific operating procedures.

Comment: I see nothing in the page you linked to (article789) that discusses the question of where to apply, let alone that it must be the country where you will stay the longest.

Comment: @Phantom it says it is recommended, true, but schengenvisainfo is not an official site.  It is very unreliable, and in this case, as in many others, it is *wrong.*  The main destination requirement is a *requirement,* and the determination of main destination does not necessarily depend on the planned duration of stay.

Comment: I see, so I will email the French embassy before the interview. Thanks!